# How can I set selected attribute for my mat-option?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, material-ui

I have the problem with my `mat-select` and `mat-option` control.
I need to set selected attribute to the first `mat-option` control without binding on `[(ngModel)]` or `[(value)]`.
My `mat-option` control is generated by `*ngFor` directive, but I don't need a property in my component, that usually binds on `[(ngModel)]` the `mat-select` UI control.
So, I tried this:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Currency</mat-label>
    <mat-select #currencySelect>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let currency of currencies; let isFirst = first" [value]="currency" [attr.selected]="isFirst ? 'selected' : null">
            {{currency | currencyName}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

and this:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Currency</mat-label>
    <mat-select #currencySelect>
        <div *ngFor="let currency of currencies; let isFirst = first">
            <mat-option *ngIf="isFirst" selected [value]="currency">
                {{currency | currencyName}}
            </mat-option>
            <mat-option *ngIf="!isFirst" [value]="currency">
                    {{currency | currencyName}}
            </mat-option>
        </div>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

and only this gave me the desired effect:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Currency</mat-label>
    <mat-select #currencySelect [value]="currencies != null && currencies.length != 0 ? currencies[0] : null">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let currency of currencies;" [value]="currency">
            {{currency | currencyName}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

but here I don't use selected attrubute. I use binding on the `[value]`, that I do not like terribly.

I would like the code to be like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Currency</mat-label>
    <mat-select #currencySelect>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let currency of currencies; let isFirst = first" [value]="currency" [selected]="isFirst">
            {{currency | currencyName}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

How can I do that? 
Once again, I don’t need a property in the component that identifies the selected item. It is important.

Comment: What about compareWith property ?

Answer (score 1):

Mat select doesn't work with an object directly, what you can do is use compareWith input on mat-select like this:

```
<mat-select [compareWith]="compareFn" [value]="initialValue"></mat-select>
```

In your Ts file, add these for example:

```
initialValue= {currencyID: 1, currencyName: 'USD'};
compareFn(a, b) {
  return a.currencyID == b.currencyID;
}
```

Comment: and so, you still created a property in the component - `initialValue`. But I don't need it.

Comment: how does your example differ from `[value]="currencies != null && currencies.length != 0 ? currencies[0] : null"`